# How to change values using arrays/arraylists to asteriks

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Im very new to Java, and I'm trying to write a program using arrays and arraylists where you enter in however many values you want, and it outputs how many values are between two parameters using asterisks. 
ex:

```
[5,14,23,43,54,15]
1-10: *
11-20: **
21-30:*
31-40: 
41-50:*
51-60: *
```

And so on. Here's what I have so far, but I'm getting errors and out of bounds exceptions. Can anyone say whether or not I'm on the right track or not? Any help is appreciated!

```
package arraylists;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numberslists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
        int [] number = new int[10];
        int x, count = 0;
        System.out.println("how many numbers would you like?");
        count = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter in those numbers please");
        for (x=0; x < count; x++){
            number[x] = reader.nextInt();
            numbers.add(number[x]);
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
        int x10 = numbers.indexOf(number[x] < 10);
        numbers.remove(x10);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace from the exception. it will identify the line of code that caused the problem. Then look at the line of code and ask yourself what's wrong at that line. (Hint: What's the value of `x` after the loop exits?) Also, since you are using a raw `ArrayList`, you're missing out on some very helpful compiler feedback. (For instance, `number[x] < 10` is a boolean value, but you don't put any `Boolean` objects into `numbers`.)

Comment: You said it calculates how many values are between 2 parameters. Where are you inputting or setting the 2 parameters you speak of?

Answer (score 2):

In short, as Lahiru said, you need to change the line: `int x10 = numbers.indexOf(number[x] < 10);`

The main problem with your code is the expression `number[x] < 10` which returns a boolean (true or false). Therefore the `numbers.indexOf(number[x] < 10)` is going to return 1 or -1.

Finally, when the code gets to `numbers.remove(x10);` and if is -1 (for false) then you will get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because there is no way to do a `numbers.remove(-1);`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29).

There is room for improvement in your code. Below is a suggestion to what you could do. But just look at this suggestion after you try fixing your own code (so you can have a better learning experience).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountOcurrancesInArray {

    private static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Use generics when possible: <Integer>
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x, count = 0;
            System.out.println("how many numbers would you like?");
            count = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter in those numbers please");
            for (x=0; x < count; x++){
                // I don't see a need for this line. number[x] = reader.nextInt();
                numbers.add(reader.nextInt());
            }
            System.out.println(numbers);
            int[] comparingNumbers = requestComparingNubers();
            System.out.println("You entered these numbers: " + numbers);
            String matchingNumbers = checkForNumbersInTheList(comparingNumbers);
            System.out.println("Numbers between " + comparingNumbers[0] + "-" + comparingNumbers[1] + ":" + matchingNumbers);
    }

    /**
     * Counts how many entries are in the list between 'comparingNumbersInput'
     * @param comparingNumbersInput
     * @return number of entries as asterisks "*"
     */
    private static String checkForNumbersInTheList(int[] comparingNumbersInput) {
        String result = "";
        for(Integer i : numbers) {
            if (i >= comparingNumbersInput[0] && i <= comparingNumbersInput[1]) {
                result += "*";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Asks the user to enter 2 numbers to be compared against the all the numbers in the list.
     * @return returns a int[2] sorted ascendingly
     */
    private static int[] requestComparingNubers() {
        int [] result = new int[2];
        System.out.println("Counting how many numbers there are in between x and y.");
        System.out.println("What is the first number?");
        result[0]=reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the second number?");
        result[1]=reader.nextInt();
        // Sort comparingList
        if (result[0] > result[1]) {
            int temp = result[1];
            result[1] = result[0];
            result[0] = temp;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perhaps a bit more flexible than the original question, but it certainly works!

Comment: That's not what he asked for, why would compare just 2 numbers and ask users to input them? Btw, you performed this task in inefficient way. You could do it all in that 1 loop.

Comment: @bedbad, correct, that's why I said that "there is room for improvement". What I am trying to present the solution the OP is looking for and at the same time present "some" improvements without confusing it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Array after getting count from user.

```
int x, count = 0;
System.out.println("how many numbers would you like?");
count = reader.nextInt();
int [] number = new int[count];
```

Also have a look at the Line of code that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this makes more sense as a Map, where you store a counter for each range found in the array of inputs. Now that means you have to first figure out what the range if that each input fits within, then update your counter that matches the range. Since we have to calculate the range as a String for output and you want the counter to be represented as a String of asterisk anyway, Storing the range as a String for the `Map.key` and the counter as a String of asterisk as the `Map.value` works nicely.

Here is some example code that does just that, where numbers is the `ArrayList` of the original values input by a user.

```
  //Declare a Map that stores the range as a String ( "01-10") as the key 
  //and a counter in astericks as the value
  Map<String,String> counters = new HashMap<>();

  //Loop over the array ov values
  for(Integer value: numbers){
    //For each value calculate the diviser by diving by 10
    Integer lowRange = value / 10;
    //To get the low range, multiply the diviser by 10 and add 1
    lowRange = (10 * lowRange) + 1;
    //The high range is 9 mor ethan the low range
    Integer highRange = lowRange + 9;
    //Finally calcualte what the range looks like as a String
    //Note that it handles "1" as a special case by prepending a "0" to make the value "01"
    String rangeString = ((lowRange < 10) ? "0" + lowRange : lowRange) + "-" + highRange;

    //Now check the map to see if the rangeString exists as a key, meaning 
    //we have previously found a value in the same range 
    String count = "";
    if(counters.containsKey(rangeString)){
      //If we found the same range, get the previous count
      count = counters.get(rangeString);
    }

    //Place the count back into the map keyed off of the range and add an asterick to the count String
    counters.put(rangeString, count + "*");
  }

  //Finally iterate over all keys in the map, printing the results of the counters for each
  for(String range: counters.keySet()){
     System.out.println(range + " " + counters.get(range));
  }
```

As an example of output, if the user inputs the values:

`[5,14,23,43,54,15,41]`

The output would be:

```
01-10 *
11-20 **
41-50 **
51-60 *
21-30 *
```

Comment: If the order of the output lines is important, consider an ordered map.  TreeMap (instead of HashMap above) is one such implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are zero-based index. For example, if you declare an array with 10 elements, the index of these elements will be from 0 to 9.

In your code snippet below, when java finishes the "for" loop

```
  for (x=0; x < count; x++){
    number[x] = reader.nextInt();
    numbers.add(number[x]);
}
```

The value of x variable will be equal to the number of elements you have inputted to the number array (x = count).

So, when you get the element at x position as below:

```
 int x10 = numbers.indexOf(number[x] < 10);
```

If x < 10, you will get -1 for x10. Then an exception will occur at:

```
 numbers.remove(x10);
```

If x >= 10, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will occur at number[x]

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Homework question

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class numberlists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedList < Integer > numbers = new LinkedList < Integer > ();
        //int [] number = new int[10]; no need, and the input is variable size
        int x, count = 0;
        System.out.println("how many numbers would you like?");
        count = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter in those numbers please");
        Map < Integer, Integer > range_numbers = new HashMap < Integer, Integer > ();


        for (x = 0; x < count; x++) {
            //number[x] = reader.nextInt();   no need
            numbers.add(reader.nextInt());
            int rs = ((int) numbers.getLast() / 10) * 10 + 1; //range start for number i.e rs(15)=11
            if (!range_numbers.containsKey(rs)) { //check if has number in that range
                range_numbers.put(rs, 1);
            } else { //gets the prev count, add 1 and stores back for range
                range_numbers.put(rs, range_numbers.get(rs) + 1);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(numbers);
        Map < Integer, Integer > sortedpairs = new TreeMap < Integer, Integer > (range_numbers); // need to sort

        for (Map.Entry < Integer, Integer > pair: sortedpairs.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("\n%d-%d: %s", pair.getKey(), pair.getKey() + 9,
                new String(new char[pair.getValue()]).replace("\0", "*"));
            //little trick to repeat any string n times
        }

    }
}
```

Enjoy.